# How to save values to localStorage with jQuery/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
                $('#buttons').on('click', 'a', function () {

                    $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
                    localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', $(this).index());
                    $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
                    $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);


                });
            });
```

```css
.current {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="buttons">
   <li>
      <a data-id="div1">One</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a data-id="div2">Two</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a data-id="div3">Three</a>
   </li>
   <li class="current">
      <a data-id="div4">Four</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<div class="pbox" id="div1">
  Content 1
</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">
    Content 2
</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">
    Content 3
</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">
    Content 4
</div>
```

What am trying to achieve is to save these values (when you click `a` element) to loaclstorage, so when I refresh the page that this class `current` doesn't disappear.

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I extracted the functionality of setting the selected element to its own function:
(hot tip, `id`s are unique. and [lookup](https://api.jquery.com/data/) `.data()` in jquery... and the HTML [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property; see last line of function)

```
  function setSelected($el) {
      $('.current').not($el.closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
      localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', $el.data('id'));
      $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
      $('#'+ $el.data('id')).show(600);
  }
```

Then, we just check for a value on load and call the same function with this value if it exists:

```
    const localID = localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue')
    if (localID) setSelected($('[data-id="' +localID + '"]'))
```

Final Javascript:

```
  function setSelected($el) {
      $('.current').not($el.closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
      localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', $el.data('id'));
      $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
      $('#'+ $el.data('id')).show(600);
  } 
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
      $('#buttons').on('click', 'a', function () {
          setSelected($(this))
      });
      const localID = localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue')
      if (localID) setSelected($('[data-id="' +localID + '"]'))
    });
```